# How to correctly handle custom URL scheme in my app (avoid handling multiple times)?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have added a custom URL scheme to my Android 4+ app to be able to deep link to some view/activity:

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
...
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
        <data android:host="webservice"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity> 



// MainActivity
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("myapp") && uri.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase("webservice")) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebServiceSettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, when a link like `myapp://webservice/something` is used, my app is startet and the `WebServiceSettingsActivity` is shown.

**BUT:** When pressing the back button, the `WebServiceSettingsActivity` is shown again. It seem, that `MainActivity` is re-startet with the same intent as before and thus the settings are shown again...

This can be repeated indefinitely. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity` is opening your `WebServiceSettingsActivity`, but you're never finishing the former. This leaves you with 2 choices:

1. Call `this.finish();` immediately after calling `startActivity(settingsIntent);`

This will kill your MainActivity so that there is nothing to return to after finishing the WebServiceSettingsActivity.

2 (better). Open your WebServiceSettingsActivity with `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`, and finish your MainActivity when, and only when, returning from your WebServiceSettingsActivity:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_WEB = 1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    ...
    if (...) {
        startActivityForResult(settingsIntent, REQUEST_CODE_WEB);
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_WEB) {
        finish(); // Or do whatever you want, such as load your main content
    }
}
```